# How to detect IIS during installation of web application using the package created by InstallShield

Tags: visual-studio, iis, installshield

Here is the wizard in Project Assistant setup by **InstallShield**. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and InstallShield 2018.

[image]

But, I do not see IIS detection configuration in above step!

How can I detect IIS is enabled or disabled in target system during InstallShield steps?

**Update**

I see **Install Condition**  property, but how do we configure the IIS check from here?

[image]

I also see some IIS configurations under **Server Configurations**. Is there a way to use this to check for IIS existence in target machine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots you're showing are asking what dependencies should it *install*.

You'll probably just want to add a LaunchCondition that checks the registry for the IIS version (VersionString) in the registry at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp.

Comment: where I can see launch condition? I found the install condition but do not see the IIS configurations. Updated the question.

Comment: In your screenshot you'll see DOTNETVERSION46FULL. Those are properties which are sort of like variables in a normal programming language. What you need to do before the LaunchCondition is set some property like IISVERSION using the RegLocator table. Then use whatever name you selected in a conditional statement where it has "New Condition" in your screenshot.

The message will be what the install will pop up with when the condition is not met.